# Strange Missing Helper File Error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initializer, view-helpers

I'm getting an unusual error in Rails...

```
Missing helper file helpers/underwrite.rb

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:6:in `call_with_quiet_assets'

This error occurred while loading the following files:
       underwrite
```

I can't find anywhere this file is being requested. If I search the entire project directory, the only reference to it is in the log files.
On some pages, the error only seems to occur the first time the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the helper file has been deleted at some stage.

In the helpers folder create a new file, rename it `underwrite.rb` and place the following code inside it.

```
module UnderwriteHelper
end
```

Comment: This worked so far, but is there a way to find where the file is being requested in the initializer that caused the initial crash? I don't see it referenced by name anywhere. I'd like to make sure I'm not losing functionality by including just the empty helper file.